# ¿Que es lo que tengo mal? Juego de dados

Tags: c++, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para el colegio de un juego de dados para 2 personas, el primero que llegue a 100 gana, si alguno de los dos sobrepasa al 100 se le resta y se sigue jugando. Es necesario recalcar que el programa tiene que llevar for para los ciclos y do while para que se repita el programa

el problema que tengo es que para los dos jugadores siempre salen los mismos numeros y no se como arreglarlo, para el jugador es 4 y para el juador 2 es 5 y siempre son sus multiplos.

el segundo problema es que cuando el jugador 1 sobrepasa la barrera de los 100 no se resta y se termina con 3 y el jugador 2 con 6

aqui el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);

int dado1=dist(gen);
int dado2=dist(gen);
int dado11=dist(gen);
int dado22=dist(gen);
char lanzar;
string j1, j2;
char opc;

do
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\t\t\t Juego de dados!"<<endl;
    cout << "\n\t Ingrese el nombre del jugador 1: ";
    cin >> j1;
    cout << "\n\n\t Ingrese el nombre del jugador 2: ";
    cin >> j2;

    for (int turno = 0;dado1 <= 100 || dado2 <= 100;)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\t "<<j1<<", es tu turno"<<endl;
        cout << "\n\t Ingrese una tecla para lanzar el dado . . ."<<endl;
        cin >> lanzar;
        cout << "\n\t El resultado es "<<dado1<<endl;
        dado1=dado1+dado1;
        system("pause");

        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\t "<<j2<<", es tu turno"<<endl;
        cout << "\n\t Ingrese una tecla para lanzar el dado . . ."<<endl;
        cin >> lanzar;
        cout << "\n\t El resultado es "<<dado2<<endl;
        dado2=dado2+dado2;
        system("pause");

        if (dado1 > 100)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n\t "<<j1<<", es tu turno"<<endl;
            cout << "\n\t Ingrese una tecla para lanzar el dado . . ."<<endl;
            cin >> lanzar;
            cout << "\n\t El resultado es "<<dado11<<endl;
            dado11=dado1-dado11;
            system("pause");
        }

        if (dado2 > 100)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n\t "<<j2<<", es tu turno"<<endl;
            cout << "\n\t Ingrese una tecla para lanzar el dado . . ."<<endl;
            cin >> lanzar;
            cout << "\n\t El resultado es "<<dado22<<endl;
            dado22=dado2-dado22;
            system("pause");
        }
    }

    if (dado1 == 100)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\t F E L I C I D A D E S!, "<<j1<<" GANASTE EL JUEGO"<<endl;
    }

    if (dado2 == 100)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\t F E L I C I D A D E S!, "<<j2<<" GANASTE EL JUEGO"<<endl;
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\t Quieres jugar de nuevo?(Y/N): ";
    cin >> opc;
 } while (opc == 'y' || opc == 'Y');

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como está planteada la condición del for: `dado1 <= 100 || dado2 <= 100`.

Fíjate que solo se detendrá cuando `dado1` y `dado2` sean mayores a 100. Por lo que los mensajes de que son mayores no se ejecutarán.

Incluso si uno de los 2 llegase a 100, el ciclo continuaría y no se informaría que uno ha ganado.

La condición debería ser, que se repita siempre que ninguno haya llegado a 100. O sea: `dado1 != 100 && dado2 != 100`.

---

En cuanto a por qué los números son siempre los mismos, una pequeña inspección basta para darse cuenta.

Al inicio del programa generas valores aleatorios:

```
int dado1=dist(gen);
int dado2=dist(gen);
int dado11=dist(gen);
int dado22=dist(gen);
```

Pero a la hora de lanzar los dados, las variables simplemente suman el mismo número que tenían guardado:

```
cout << "\n\t El resultado es "<<dado1<<endl;
dado1=dado1+dado1;
```

Lo mismo sucede con `dado2`. Por lo tanto no hay más azar que al inicio del programa.

Para que el valor cambie a uno aleatorio, deberías volver a ejecutar `dist(gen)`.

Tendrías un código como:

```
dado1 += dist(gen);
// Es lo mismo que dado1 = dado1 + dist(gen);
```

---

Con lo anterior resuelto, te darás cuenta de que hay un problema más.

Como cuando `dado1` o `dado2` supera 100 el resultado de la resta se guarda en `dado11` o `dado22` y no reflejas el cambio en las variables `dado1` y `dado2`,  simplemente parece que la resta no sucede.

Ya que `dado11` y `dado22` no tienen otros usos en el código, puedes simplemente borrarlas.

En lugar de:

```
dado11=dado1-dado11;
```

Te quedará:

```
dado1 = dado1 - cantidadARestar;
```

Lo mismo aplica a `dado22`.

---

Por último, si vuelves a jugar notarás que automáticamente ganará el mismo jugador que ya ganó.

Esto porque no reinicias las variables cada vez que inicias una partida nueva.

Puedes ver cómo funciona el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##zVbbbtNAEH33V0yN1DqiDc0igUqcoArSqlEVhAIPlSpVW3ubbGTvWnspFJpvQ@LHwqzt3IiTEAECO5bj47md4/Gsoyw7ihIqBpPJEy6ixMYMQi61UYymbW@OaRMn/LY@XMQMT9kyoqiIJfp5VnMxAEFTpjMaMUD3pudxYSClXAQ176sHuBX2NzG752ik0MahqWmcnDx/CQMmAhUHtVoBW8HvpEpvMMpNzLFEfmsNlyJEoA0OCRqH8AKtc3OXLKaxRMydSBEkGlIFSPgLVQXg4mCpIzQbLdrILCqvpNCGfc5UHlExbfBuCxrHVbeRh5GKUzQgx2UhscxPBeM85QN6pIEfJdovuRWRrIEwBP9aXBu3Q9eygQQU1hHQe34YMhEnazzgQgywOgYsASHTW4Vu@HdkB@isoPEK/AVPLqDdRtbVwbaHI5XhSEk5p@20Rx2Om0sQKaAZ9mnIExYUxnutuYD7@6X5Alibec3F3CDoqkSo4KgRhv4hMA3G4k8JuSLremmtoGAYvjCQUUXLPnIKuVKh7vbqaIU@075buldQf9oqOhh7fiODTuJa0CbGJUQSmC4PUJV1KktGrWZ@7ae8O4lG/kPRyO@KRnYXjd9B2avtiq5c7cwtQm/qUMNQL03Rtw595i5jpnHa4PiRAnznUg4j5wyZFUbq@rXwt6XYpYXmDXrUKtM1dyE4rpaP/E35yD@Rj2ySj6yTb@xVKLWG8bz3WttH4nLNZ9CBS7iAN3i8hVM8OtDfO5x1G5yf9k77HzrQuYTux875u5UXcl6ot/ow/2g95Bfr2Wk5/f7tveUMn0C@gCm3pgrL7uXr4OpZr1a1ls3WfxgXaxQECDmqBw8H8PgI06urg@mQUMyNRre6jSeTLsWvI@/M4viS3sLW@wE).